# How to change textbox to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code for selecting font family from drop down list to textbox. Now I want to use textarea in place of text box. How can I do this?

```
<HTML>
<head>


<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


<script>
$(function () {
    $('select[name="font"]').on('change', function () {
        $('input[name="text1"]').css('font-family', this.value);
    });
});
</script>
</head>



<body>
Select Programming font:
<select name="font">
    <option value="arial">arial black</option>
    <option value="tohma">tahoma</option>
    <option value="times new roman">times new roman</option>
    <option value="calibri">calibri</option>
</select>



<br>EnterValue:
 <input type="text" name="text1" value="Font Family">

</body>
</html>
```

I tried

Comment: didn't understand your question are you trying to change your textbox to textarea when selecting a font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change:

```
<input type="text" name="text1" value="Font Family" />
```

to:

```
<textarea>Font Family</textarea>
```

then use:

```
$('textarea').css('font-family', this.value);
```

instead of:

```
$('input[name="text1"]').css('font-family', this.value);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K6X4q/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<textarea name="text1" id="text1">Font Family</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="text-input" type="text" name="text1" value="Font Family">

var value = $('#text-input').val();
$('#text-input').replace('<textarea id="text-input" name="text1"></textarea >');
$('#text-input').val(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method to change from input box to texarea like below:

```
$('input[name="text1"]').replaceWith('<textarea />');
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
function t2t( el ) {
    var element = document.getElementById( el.id );
  var parent = element.parentNode;
  parent.removeChild( element );
  parent.innerHTML = element.type == 'text' ? '<textarea id="' + element.id + '" cols=50 rows=5>' + element.value +'</textarea>' : '<input type="text" id="' + element.id + '"  value="' + element.value + '" />';
}
```